# Why do I get an exception loading a nested class in Android via Groovy in API 24?

Tags: android, groovy, grooid

As an example, dynamically loading the following code using the groovyshell-example app found here: https://github.com/pieces029/grooidshell-example/tree/update/build-tools-and-scripts:

```
def class Outer {
    def class Inner {}
}
new Outer.Inner()
```

#### Result in Android Emulator API 23

```
Result = Outer$Inner@a9ea1cd
```

#### Result in Android Emulator API 24

```
Result = null
```

#### Stacktrace in API 24

```
08-13 02:23:03.233 3147-3147/me.champeau.groovydroid E/GrooidShell: Dynamic loading failed!
    BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'script14710549832242032452851.groovy' throw with null exception
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:935)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:593)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:542)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:254)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:211)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:221)
        at me.champeau.groovydroid.GrooidShell.evaluate(GrooidShell.java:85)
        at me.champeau.groovydroid.GroovyActivity.generateMessage(GroovyActivity.groovy:38)
        at me.champeau.groovydroid.GroovyActivity.executeCode(GroovyActivity.groovy:31)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4693)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: throw with null exception
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:371)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:677)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:545)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.tryAsLoaderClassOrScript(ClassNodeResolver.java:185)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.findClassNode(ClassNodeResolver.java:170)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.resolveName(ClassNodeResolver.java:126)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveToOuter(ResolveVisitor.java:676)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolve(ResolveVisitor.java:308)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveNestedClass(ResolveVisitor.java:341)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolve(ResolveVisitor.java:308)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolve(ResolveVisitor.java:276)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveOrFail(ResolveVisitor.java:260)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveOrFail(ResolveVisitor.java:272)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transformConstructorCallExpression(ResolveVisitor.java:1047)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transform(ResolveVisitor.java:706)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.visitExpressionStatement(ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.java:142)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:42)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(CodeVisitorSupport.java:37)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:166)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitBlockStatement(ResolveVisitor.java:1318)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:71)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClassCodeContainer(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:104)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:115)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.java:53)
08-13 02:23:03.234 3147-3147/me.champeau.groovydroid E/GrooidShell:     at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitConstructorOrMethod(ResolveVisitor.java:201)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:126)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.visitContents(ClassNode.java:1078)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClass(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:53)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitClass(ResolveVisitor.java:1261)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.startResolving(ResolveVisitor.java:176)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$11.call(CompilationUnit.java:651)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:931)
            ... 21 more
```

Comment: You don't need def in front of the class, but I'm not sure if that would cause this issue, You should try to get the compiled class file from on the device and disassembling it to see what it's trying to do.

Comment: Just using the new keyword seems to cause the same error on API 24.

`new String('hello')`

will also cause the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

The version of the DX library included in that project is 1.7. Where the best I can tell by opening up the dx.jar file included with the latest (24.1.1) build tools is 1.12. I am guessing that similar to Java backwards compatibility is kept in place but lower versions will not run on newer version.

On that note, I would guess that someone just posted the dx jar to central and that is not an official google release. I think the best bet would be to reference the jar that is included in the build tools you are compiling with.

Comment: I updated the project you listed to use the latest dx jar. https://github.com/pieces029/grooidshell-example/tree/update-dx-version I'm still seeing issues though. Posting to hopefully help debug.